# QML Unable to change position of item while being dragged by MouseArea

Tags: c++, qt, qml

**Context**

I am trying to create a tiled map using QML without using QtLocation. I am trying to design the application such that only essential tiles are being loaded. Here is the strategy I have come up with.

Each tile is 256x256 px. The tiles are placed in a Grid class with nested Repeaters. The xOffset determines the tiles that should be loaded into the grid.

```
        Grid{
            id: mapgrid
            rows: 6
            columns: 9
            spacing: 1
            Repeater{
                model: 6
                Repeater{
                    model: 9
                    property int outerIndex: index
                    Tile{
                        imgsrc: "image://provider/" + maprect.zoomLevel + '/' + (index + maprect.xOffset) + '/' + (outerIndex+maprect.yOffset)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When the grid is shifted by 256 pixels left, a new set of tiles should be loaded in. This can be achieved by changing the offset values. I can then shift the grid by 256 pixels again so its back in the view.

```
        onXChanged: {
            if(x <= -512){
                maprect.x = -256;
                maprect.xOffset++;
            }
        }
```

**Problem**

The movement of my grid is controlled by a MouseArea with drag.target set to it. It appears that the MouseArea controls the coordinates until the mouse is released. Here is a simple example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Text{
        z:1
        text: "X: " + rect.x
    }

    MouseArea{
        id:marea
        anchors.fill: rect
        drag.target: rect

    }

    Rectangle{
        id: rect
        height: 256
        width: 256
        color: "red"
        onXChanged: {
            if(x > 100){
                x = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you move the box right past x > 100, indeed x=0 is set. However that is because the actual value of the box is still 100+. If you move the box left again (x<100) without releasing, you'll find that the box is back at its actual x value. Sorry if it sounds confusing, its easier to understand to see it for yourself.

What I am looking for is an alternative way to load tiles or a fix to the MouseArea problem such that I can actually change the position of an item while its being dragged by the MouseArea.

Also, would it be possible for me to implement a different version of MouseArea so I can deal with this problem at a lower abstraction?

**Update**

I have been able to achieve the effect I wanted to a certain degree. It appears to be working fine but QML is detecting a binding loop.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: wind
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle{
        id: wrapper
        height: wind.height
        width: wind.width
        MouseArea{
            id:marea
            anchors.fill: wrapper
            //drag.target: rect

            property int initialX: 0

            property int iniMouseX;
            onEntered: {
                initialX = rect.x
                iniMouseX = mouseX
                console.log ("set")
            }
        }

        Rectangle{
            id: rect
            height: 256
            width: 256
            border.color: "green"
            x: marea.initialX + (marea.mouseX - marea.iniMouseX)
            color: "red"

            onXChanged: {
                if(rect.x > 200){
                    marea.initialX -= 200;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5qqh.jpg

Comment: What are the result you except? if rect drag out of x:100, even mouse still not released, you want the rect stay in x: 0 until it is pressed again?

Comment: @Jiu I would like the rect to be shifted to x = 0, then I can continue to drag it again until x > 100, back to x = 0 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the updated code is `initialX` bind with `rect.x`, so if `rect.x` be updated it will invoke `onXChanged`, and if `rect.x > 200` will update `initialX` again, this will become an infinite loop. 
So to fix it here is the solution, make the event goes like flow :

```
Window {
    id: wind
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle{
        id: wrapper
        height: wind.height
        width: wind.width
        MouseArea{
            id:marea
            anchors.fill: wrapper
            //drag.target: rect

            property int initialX: 0

            property int iniMouseX;
            onEntered: {
                initialX = rect.x
                iniMouseX = mouseX
                console.log ("set")
            }
            onMouseXChanged: {
                if(rect.x > 200){
                    marea.initialX -= 200;
                }
                rect.x = marea.initialX + (marea.mouseX - marea.iniMouseX)
            }
        }

        Rectangle{
            id: rect
            height: 256
            width: 256
            border.color: "green"
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but this is not what i am looking for. Here is a gif to illustrate what I want : https://imgur.com/a/zmu5eiO

Comment: @gxexx I fixed the **update** code error, take a look the new answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for explaining and helping me to fix the binding loop problem!